# mysql subquery - results do not fulfill both

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following SQL query for MySQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS objects.objects_no 
FROM objects 
LEFT JOIN finds ON (objects.objects_no = finds.objects_no) 
LEFT JOIN ceramics ON (objects.objects_no = ceramics.objects_no) 
WHERE 1=1 
and (objects.objects_no) in (select DISTINCT objects_no from objects_materials where thesaurus_term_id in (18658)) 
and (objects.objects_no) in (select DISTINCT objects_no from objects_objects where thesaurus_term_id in (24193)) 
GROUP BY objects.objects_no 
ORDER BY objects.objects_no
```

Instead of getting results that match both subqueries, I also get results that match one or the other. Does anyone have an idea why that is?

Thanks, Sandro

Comment: because you are doing a group by without any aggregate columns. So it is a trick query for the equivalent of doing give me the first one per grouping?

Comment: @Drew . . . No, it is effectively doing `select distinct`.

Comment: select distinct, give me one per grouping, same difference.

Comment: People do that to improve the performance vs Distinct.

Comment: I doubt it will make a difference, but I can't see anything obviously wrong with the query... have you tried removing the parenthesis around the `(objects.objects_no)`'s in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that reproduces the problem? It looks to me like it should work as desired.

Comment: Neither adding nor removing parenthesis did help.

Answer (score 0):

Try parenthesizing the conditions.

```
WHERE (
  (1=1) 
  and ((objects.objects_no) in (select DISTINCT objects_no from objects_materials where thesaurus_term_id in (18658)))
  and ((objects.objects_no) in (select DISTINCT objects_no from objects_objects where thesaurus_term_id in (24193)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that did not work as well. I am really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. It actually does work just fine. There was a problem within the data inside the thesaurus.
Sorry!!!